# Hadoop Mapreduce Error on EC2 - Call from master/ip to master:9000 failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

so I set up a simple 2-node hadoop cluster on a private AWS VPC. So I am using a private IP and DNS instead of the public IP they give you AWS.

I have HDFS up and running, and I can use the filesystem to create and move files/directories. But when I try to run simple Mapreduce jobs such as wordcount, I get the following error:

```
 Call From master/10.205.232.248 to master:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/10.205.232.248 to master:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

My /etc/hosts look like this:

```
10.205.232.248 <master_hostname> ip-10-205-232-248 master
10.205.232.249 <slave_hostname> ip-10-205-232-249 slave
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4
```

My core-site.xml:

```
<property>
 <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
</property>
```

My mapred-site.xml:

```
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
                <value>yarn</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
                <value>10.205.232.248:9001</value>
        </property>
```

My yarn-site.xml:

```
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
                <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHander</value>
        </property>
```

What configuration setting have I overlooked to get this connection error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall in machines and ports are opened in aws security groups(inbound and outbound)

Comment: I did, and it is open for all ports.

Comment: login into master and ping slave nodes.